# Is there a way to UPSERT an Oracle Foreign Table with Foreign Data Wrapper from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, oracle-fdw

I need to transfer lots of row from my PostgreSQL database to a remote Oracle DB through the Oracle Foreign Data Wrapper (FDW). The preferred way to do it is by UPSERT.

However as INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT can not be used for Foreign Table, hence I am using the following that work quite well.

```
WITH 
my_input (
    SELECT ...
),
my_update (
    UPDATE  my_foreign_table f 
    SET     ...
    FROM    my_input i
    WHERE   f.id=i.id
    RETURNING ...
)
INSERT   INTO my_foreign_table f 
SELECT   ...
FROM     my_input 
WHERE    NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT   1 FROM my_foreign_table f
         WHERE    f.id=a.id )
```

Now I am curious: Is there a way to do this in a more straight-forward way through Oracle FDW from PostgreSQL other than the above way ? I fear that the above way might not be efficient.

FYI, my playground:

- PostgreSQL 9.6.11 64-bit with PostGIS 2.5.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
- Oracle DB 11.2.0.4.0 64-bit

Comment: No, I cannot think of a better way. Make sure that there are no concurrent data modifications on the Oracle table, else you either will get a serialization error or (if you have set `isolation_level` to `read_committed`) there could be a race condition.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe In the event I only care for INSERT and not UPSERT, does your suggestion for "no concurrent data modifications on the Oracle table" remain?

Comment: Then there would be no race condition, but with oracle_fdw's isolation level you could still see serialization errors, because Oracle's implementation of `SERIALIZABLE` is really bad (I have no other word to describe it).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe SERIALIZABLE. Got that. I hear it a lot from you. :)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Wait, it just occurred to me to ask: Is this kind of SERIALIZABLE implementation remain the same over all Oracle RDBMS version, or only upto certain Oracle RDBMS version ?

Comment: For all versions. It is not important for `INSERT`s, so it is safe to change it in that case, but in general, a single PostgreSQL query might result in several Oracle queries, which should return consistent results.